# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in my method

Tags: python, string, pygame, typeerror

I have been trying to design a snake game in python but after having implementing the part of the code that make the body of the snake move (not the head) I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I looked online and all I found was just saying that I should not call my variable 'str' and I didn't so I am kind of confused.
This is the class:

```
class snake(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,h_dir,b_dir):
        self.X=x
        self.Y=y
        self.h_dir=h_dir
        self.b_dir=b_dir
    
    def direction(self):
        global head_direction
        self.direction=head_direction
        if(self.X==turn_X and self.Y==turn_Y):
            self.direction=head_direction
        return self.direction
```

Here is where the error occur:

```
for i in range(1,snakeLength):
        if(body[i].direction()=='UP'):
            body[i].Y-=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='RIGHT'):
            body[i].X+=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='DOWN'):
            body[i].Y+=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='LEFT'):
            body[i].X-=20
        pygame.draw.rect(window, grey, (body[i].X, body[i].Y, 20, 20))
```

and here is the whole code:

```
    # Libraries
    import pygame
    from time import*

running=True
while running:
    # Initialisation
    pygame.init()

    # Quit programm
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if(event.type==pygame.QUIT):
                running=False

    # Class
    class snake(object):
        def __init__(self,x,y,h_dir,b_dir):
            self.X=x
            self.Y=y
            self.h_dir=h_dir
            self.b_dir=b_dir
        
        def direction(self):
            global head_direction
            self.direction=head_direction
            if(self.X==turn_X and self.Y==turn_Y):
                self.direction=head_direction
            return self.direction

    # Functions
    def displayScore():
        score_font=pygame.font.Font('/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Snake/G7StarForceTtf-OEg6.ttf',20)
        score_surface=score_font.render('SCORE '+score, True, white)
        window.blit(score_surface, (0,500))
        pygame.display.update()

    def gameOver():
        window.fill((green))
        global alive
        gameOver_font=pygame.font.Font('/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Snake/G7StarForceTtf-OEg6.ttf',50)
        gameOver_surface=gameOver_font.render('GAME OVER', True, white)
        gameOver_rect=gameOver_surface.get_rect(center=(window_X/2, window_Y/2))
        score_font=pygame.font.Font('/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Snake/G7StarForceTtf-OEg6.ttf',20)
        score_surface=score_font.render('YOUR FINAL SCORE IS '+score, True, white)
        window.blit(score_surface, (0,500))
        window.blit(gameOver_surface, (gameOver_rect))
        pygame.display.update()
        sleep(3)
        alive=False

    # Window size
    window_X=500
    window_Y=520

    # Colors
    green=pygame.Color(153,255,153)
    black=pygame.Color(0,0,0)
    grey=pygame.Color(32,32,32)
    red=pygame.Color(255,0,0)
    white=pygame.Color(255,255,255)

    # Window
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
    window=pygame.display.set_mode((window_X,window_Y))
    icon=pygame.image.load('/Users/claudiabergeron/Documents/Python/Tutoriels/Video games/Pygame/Snake/anaconda.png')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    # FPS
    fps=pygame.time.Clock()

    # Head
    head_X=240
    head_Y=240
    head_direction='RIGHT'
    head_no_direction='LEFT'

    # Tail
    body=['head']
    snakeLength=5
    turn_X=-1
    turn_Y=-1

    # Snake
    snake_speed=5

    # Score
    score=0

    for i in range(0,snakeLength):
        body.append(i)
    for i in range(snakeLength):
        body_X=head_X-(20*i)
        body_Y=head_Y
        body_direction=head_direction
        body[i]=snake(body_X, body_Y, head_direction, body_direction)
    alive=True
    while alive:
        window.fill((green))
        # Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if(event.type==pygame.QUIT):
                running=False
                alive=False
            
            # Keystrokes
            if(event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                turn_X=head_X
                turn_Y=head_Y
                if(event.key==pygame.K_UP):
                    if(head_no_direction!='UP'):
                        head_direction='UP'
                        head_no_direction='DOWN'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    if(head_no_direction!='RIGHT'):
                        head_direction='RIGHT'
                        head_no_direction='LEFT'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
                    if(head_no_direction!='DOWN'):
                        head_direction='DOWN'
                        head_no_direction='UP'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                    if(head_no_direction!='LEFT'):
                        head_direction='LEFT'
                        head_no_direction='RIGHT'

        # Head
        pygame.draw.rect(window, black, (head_X, head_Y, 20, 20))
        if(head_direction=='UP'):
            head_Y-=20
        if(head_direction=='RIGHT'):
            head_X+=20
        if(head_direction=='DOWN'):
            head_Y+=20
        if(head_direction=='LEFT'):
            head_X-=20

        # Body
        for i in range(1,snakeLength):
            if(body[i].direction()=='UP'):
                body[i].Y-=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='RIGHT'):
                body[i].X+=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='DOWN'):
                body[i].Y+=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='LEFT'):
                body[i].X-=20
            pygame.draw.rect(window, grey, (body[i].X, body[i].Y, 20, 20))
            
            

        # Updates
        pygame.draw.rect(window, red, (0, 0, 500, 500),3)
        displayScore()
        pygame.display.update()
        fps.tick(snake_speed)

        # Game over
        if(head_X==500 or head_X==-20 or head_Y==500 or head_Y==-20):
            gameOver()
```

I need help.

Comment: What line is the error on? Paste the complete error trace!

Comment: this whole section: if(body[i].direction()=='UP'):
                body[i].Y-=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='RIGHT'):
                body[i].X+=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='DOWN'):
                body[i].Y+=20
            if(body[i].direction()=='LEFT'):
                body[i].X-=20

Comment: Some general things: Inheriting from `object` is no longer needed in Python 3. `if(foo):` is not common in python, use `if foo:` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
   for i in range(1,snakeLength):
        if(body[i].direction()=='UP'):
            body[i].Y-=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='RIGHT'):
            body[i].X+=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='DOWN'):
            body[i].Y+=20
        if(body[i].direction()=='LEFT'):
            body[i].X-=20
        pygame.draw.rect(window, grey, (body[i].X, body[i].Y, 20, 20))
```

Should look like this:

```
for i in range(1,snakeLength):
    if(body[i].direction=='UP'):
        body[i].Y-=20
    if(body[i].direction=='RIGHT'):
        body[i].X+=20
    if(body[i].direction=='DOWN'):
        body[i].Y+=20
    if(body[i].direction=='LEFT'):
        body[i].X-=20
    pygame.draw.rect(window, grey, (body[i].X, body[i].Y, 20, 20))
```

Your code has a few other issues that popped up, but this worked for me to resolve your issue.

If you are still having trouble, here is my completed code that ran without error.  Please note, I replaced your icon and font filenames so that I could use resources available on my machine.

(spoilers!)

```
# Libraries
import pygame
from time import*

running=True
while running:
    # Initialisation
    pygame.init()

    # Quit programm
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if(event.type==pygame.QUIT):
                running=False

    # Class
    class snake(object):
        def __init__(self,x,y,h_dir,b_dir):
            self.X=x
            self.Y=y
            self.h_dir=h_dir
            self.b_dir=b_dir
            
        def direction(self):
            global head_direction
            self.direction=head_direction
            if(self.X==turn_X and self.Y==turn_Y):
                self.direction=head_direction
            return self.direction

    # Functions
    def displayScore():
        score_font=pygame.font.Font('Debrosee-ALPnL.ttf',20)
        score_surface=score_font.render('SCORE '+str(score), True, white)
        window.blit(score_surface, (0,500))
        pygame.display.update()

    def gameOver():
        window.fill((green))
        global alive
        gameOver_font=pygame.font.Font('Debrosee-ALPnL.ttf',50)
        gameOver_surface=gameOver_font.render('GAME OVER', True, white)
        gameOver_rect=gameOver_surface.get_rect(center=(window_X/2, window_Y/2))
        score_font=pygame.font.Font('Debrosee-ALPnL.ttf',20)
        score_surface=score_font.render('YOUR FINAL SCORE IS '+str(score), True, white)
        window.blit(score_surface, (0,500))
        window.blit(gameOver_surface, (gameOver_rect))
        pygame.display.update()
        sleep(3)
        alive=False

    # Window size
    window_X=500
    window_Y=520

    # Colors
    green=pygame.Color(153,255,153)
    black=pygame.Color(0,0,0)
    grey=pygame.Color(32,32,32)
    red=pygame.Color(255,0,0)
    white=pygame.Color(255,255,255)

    # Window
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
    window=pygame.display.set_mode((window_X,window_Y))
    icon=pygame.image.load('anaconda.png')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    # FPS
    fps=pygame.time.Clock()

    # Head
    head_X=240
    head_Y=240
    head_direction='RIGHT'
    head_no_direction='LEFT'

    # Tail
    body=['head']
    snakeLength=5
    turn_X=-1
    turn_Y=-1

    # Snake
    snake_speed=5

    # Score
    score=0

    for i in range(0,snakeLength):
        body.append(i)
    for i in range(snakeLength):
        body_X=head_X-(20*i)
        body_Y=head_Y
        body_direction=head_direction
        body[i]=snake(body_X, body_Y, head_direction, body_direction)
        alive=True
    while alive:
        window.fill((green))
        # Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if(event.type==pygame.QUIT):
                running=False
                alive=False
                
            # Keystrokes
            if(event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                turn_X=head_X
                turn_Y=head_Y
                if(event.key==pygame.K_UP):
                    if(head_no_direction!='UP'):
                        head_direction='UP'
                        head_no_direction='DOWN'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    if(head_no_direction!='RIGHT'):
                        head_direction='RIGHT'
                        head_no_direction='LEFT'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
                    if(head_no_direction!='DOWN'):
                        head_direction='DOWN'
                        head_no_direction='UP'
                elif(event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                    if(head_no_direction!='LEFT'):
                        head_direction='LEFT'
                        head_no_direction='RIGHT'

        # Head
        pygame.draw.rect(window, black, (head_X, head_Y, 20, 20))
        if(head_direction=='UP'):
            head_Y-=20
        if(head_direction=='RIGHT'):
            head_X+=20
        if(head_direction=='DOWN'):
            head_Y+=20
        if(head_direction=='LEFT'):
            head_X-=20

        # Body
        for i in range(1,snakeLength):
            if(body[i].direction=='UP'):
                body[i].Y-=20
            if(body[i].direction=='RIGHT'):
                body[i].X+=20
            if(body[i].direction=='DOWN'):
                body[i].Y+=20
            if(body[i].direction=='LEFT'):
                body[i].X-=20
                pygame.draw.rect(window, grey, (body[i].X, body[i].Y, 20, 20))
                
            

        # Updates
        pygame.draw.rect(window, red, (0, 0, 500, 500),3)
        displayScore()
        pygame.display.update()
        fps.tick(snake_speed)

        # Game over
        if(head_X==500 or head_X==-20 or head_Y==500 or head_Y==-20):
            gameOver()
```

Comment: It worked I no longer have any errors but the body doesn't move why is that???

Comment: With the code I just added, it seems to move OK.  It won't turn and move in opposite direction, but that seems to be purposeful and makes sense in a snake game.

Comment: what else have you changed?

Comment: I added explicit type-casting in the functions where you are doing some concatenation.  I think that was about it.